# How to fix "error:assignment to expression with array type"?

Tags: c

I'm getting an error:

> error:assignment to expression with array type

in this program, which should print words that have 4-8 letters:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char rec[300];
   int zbroj1=0, br=0, zbroj2=0;

   while((rec=getchar()) != '\n')
   {
     zbroj1++;
   }
   if(zbroj1>=4 || zbroj1<=8)
    printf("Nova recenica je: %s", zbroj1);

   return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: And what is that error?

Comment: Something with assignment on array type

Comment: Please show the verbatim error message.

Comment: error:assignment to expression with array type

Comment: @Arthuoff: Thank you. Now the reason is crystal clear; there are two problems with the code, not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code to print words of size >= 4 and <= 8

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char rec[9];   //you may need to adjust the buffer according to the size of the words
    int br=0, zbroj2=0;

    while((zbroj2=getchar()) != '\n') {
        if(br < 8)
            rec[br] = zbroj2;    // we are not going to store the words having length more than 8
        br++;
        if(zbroj2 == 32){
            if(br>4 && br<=8){
                rec[br] = '\0';
                printf("Nova recenica je: %s\n", rec);
            }
            br = 0;
        }
    }
    if(br>=4 && br<=8){    // This check is to catch the last word
        rec[br] = '\0';
        printf("Nova recenica je: %s\n", rec);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is it, null char is so irritating.

Comment: @Arthuoff, the null character indeed must be accounted for and / or provided, but that has nothing to do with the error you asked about.  Compare the loop condition in this answer's `while` loop to the analogous one in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is where the error is coming from...

```
rec=getchar()
```

...as `rec` is an array of `char` and `getchar()` returns a character as an `int`. Using the unused variable `br` to store that return value, and the counter variable `zbroj1` as an index into the array you can build up `rec` using the following code:

```
while((br=getchar()) != '\n')
{
    rec[zbroj1]=br;
    zbroj1++;
}
```

Strings in C need to have a `\0` character at the end to terminate them so you'll also need to have the line to finish it

```
rec[zbroj1]='\0';
```

And then your code to check the length has a logical error - it's using `||` which means either expression has to be true and you're printing out a string, so you want to use `&&` (and) to ensure that `zbroj1` is inbetween 4 & 8 inclusively.

```
if(zbroj1>=4 && zbroj1<=8)
```

Finally, you're outputting a string, but passing an `int`. To print out the word, you need to pass in the string you've built in `rec`

```
 printf("Nova recenica je: %s", rec);
```

Putting all this corrections together gets you this final version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char rec[300];
   int zbroj1=0, br=0, zbroj2=0;

   while((br=getchar()) != '\n')
   {
     rec[zbroj1]=br;
     zbroj1++;
   }
   rec[zbroj1]='\0';
   if(zbroj1>=4 && zbroj1<=8)
    printf("Nova recenica je: %s", re);


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getchar` does **not** return a `char`.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite oops! corrected that

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues. First one is with return value of `getchar()`. This

```
rec=getchar()
```

surely causes warning as `getchar()` returns type is of `int` not of type of `rec`. 
From the manual page of [getchar()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar)

> ```
> int getchar(void);
> ```
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> `getchar()` return the character read as an unsigned char cast to an
>   `int` or `EOF` on end of file or error.

And secondaly use logical-And `&&` instaed of logical-OR `||` as `&&` prints `rec` if `zbroj1` is between `4` and `8` i.e when both condition are true , for e.g

```
if(zbroj1>=4 && zbroj1<=8)
```

Working code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
   int ret; 
   char rec[300];
   int zbroj1=0, br=0, zbroj2=0;

   while((ret=getchar()) != '\n') {
     rec[zbroj1] = ret; /* you need to store into array */
     zbroj1++;
   }
   rec[zbroj1] = '\0'; /* terminate the array with \0 */

   if(zbroj1>=4 && zbroj1<=8) /* use logical && */
    printf("Nova recenica je: %s", rec); /* use %d as zbroj1 is of int type*/
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I get this but this will only give me number how many words of that letters are  like(2,5,7,8).It does not print that exact words between 4-8.I'll give you example to better understand it.Sentence: "I'm a very good student", and it needs to print only: "very", "good" and "student", not "I'm" or "a".

Comment: modified @Arthuoff

Comment: Still, not printing words

Comment: What input you gave ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code :

- you're assigning to an array :

  `while((rec=getchar()) != '\n')`

  [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns a `int`, so `rec` should be defined as such :

  `int rec;`
- you're printing an `int` as if it were a string :

  `printf("Nova recenica je: %s", zbroj1);`

  This is undefined behavior. Use the correct format specifier :

  `printf("Nova recenica je: %d", zbroj1);`
- your if check does not do what you expect :

  `if(zbroj1>=4 || zbroj1<=8)`

  This covers all values. You probably meant :

  `if(zbroj1>=4 && zbroj1<=8)`

Comment: `int rec` is not what he wants. He wants `rec[zbroj1]= getchar()`. And he must terminate with `\0` and then print `rec` as a string. Can you adapt your answer?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie : Doing all the op wants would amount to rewriting the entire code for her/him (including splitting up sentences in words etc.). That's not what (I consider) this site is for. I've addressed the errors in the code - next steps should be taken by the op (possibly asking further specific questions if needed).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie : case in point : the op accepted the answer that rewrote the code without explanation, and without even mentioning the errors. Sometimes, everyone loses.